# To generate larger number of Prime Numbers

Tags: primes

I'm working on a homework to generate as much prime numbers as you can.
I used *Sieve of Eratosthenes* to generate prime number less than 10,000,000. I want to generate more. How can I generate more prime numbers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For small *n*, a segmented Sieve of Eratosthenes should work. For large *n*, generate candidates with a wheel then test with Miller-Rabin. The line between small and large depends on your aspirations and your budget. I discuss generating the first billion primes at [my blog](http://programmingpraxis.com/2012/09/11/the-sum-of-the-first-billion-primes/).

Answer (score 0):

While there are many algorithms for finding prime numbers, the biggest bang for your buck comes from the Sieve of Eratosthenes because you are spending order [O(log n * log log n)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes#Algorithm_complexity) time for each number that you test.  So to gain big, you want to optimize your sieve of Eratosthenes, and most likely your problem is memory.  Consider the following optimizations:

- Use only a single bit per item in your array (allows you to get 8 times as many elements in memory in comparison to the byte approach).

  Don't store the even numbers.  Sieve only only the odd numbers (allows you to get 2 time as many elements in memory).

  Being clever, you also avoid storing those which are divisible by 3.  I won't give you the answer to this, but at this point it is becoming diminishing returns.

  Think about: once you have the set of primes between (1..x], how can you use those to sieve a different interval between (x..y].  Free up your (1..x] memory so you can allocate (x..y] memory.

  Don't be shy to use disk space for extra memory.